# Badges on the image bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to place badges on the image like on the example picture below. I have bad experience with css so if somebody will help me I will appreciate it.

```css
.product {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  width: 360px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.image-product {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.image-product > a,
.image-product img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product clearfix">
  <div class="image-product">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://richthediabetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Pizza.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a img tag for badge on top of the image

```
<div class="product clearfix">    
    <div class="image-product">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="badgeOne" src="http://richthediabetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Pizza.jpg" />
            <img src="http://richthediabetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Pizza.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add the badgeOne class to css like this

```
.product {
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  width: 360px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.image-product {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.image-product > a,
.image-product img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.badgeOne {position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    border: 1px solid;}
```

Play around with it according to your need...

Here is a sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tqw2nLk/)